# req.body is empty when when header is { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }

Tags: http, express, angular, typescript, angular2-universal

I am using Angular 2 as front end. I tried to send an Object `{ test: 'Hi' }`.

When my http header is like this:

```
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

I can get the content I sent on the server side using `req.body`.

However, when my http header is like this:

```
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token });
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

When I use `req.body` again, I got an empty Object `{}`.

My server is using Express.js, and my bodyParser is like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

How can I do it correctly? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with both headers?

Comment: @RobM. thanks for the tip! I updated a little of my question, because I am not sure how to use both headers in Angular 2..

Comment: No problem, this should work: `let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization: 'Bearer ....' });`

Comment: @RobM. it works perfect! Would you mind moving to answer, so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send both headers to express:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ....' 
});
```